# Does Null Hypothesis H0 in point pattern analysis have to be CSR?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spatial

I'm taking some tests on the Cells dataset (Diggle 1983). Tests include Chi / quadrant and Nearest Neighbor.

[image: Cells Diggle 1983]

By the looks of it, it's very not random. My H0 should therefore be that it is Dispersed. But what would the Z value for acceptance or rejection be in that case?

Comment: Dispersed is a single word here,  but when quantified, it is a range of possibilities, i.e. more dispersed than random. That's a reason why CSR is a starting point in this kind of analysis. There seems no reason why a particular model of dispersion would not be a good starting point, but there is, to my knowledge, no general model that could serve easily here.

Comment: Thanks again Nick. So H0 is always CSR?

Comment: No; I didn't say that. It just seems customary in literature I've seen.

Comment: Usually CSR is the first H0 one looks at, and in your case it will be rejected by any reasonable test. Then you could come up with a plausible model for the data as your H0 and maybe fail to reject that H0 (which really doesn't prove that it is a good model, but at least the model would then appear to be more appropriate than CSR). If you do a Monte Carlo test you can really use any H0 that you are able to generate realisations from.

Comment: @EgeRubak that sounds like an acceptable answer. Can you please answer? Ill accept. An example for Monte Carlo with something other than CSR as H0 would be appreciated for future readers I reckon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually CSR is the first H0 one looks at, and in your case it will be rejected by any reasonable test. Then you could come up with a plausible model for the data as your H0 and maybe fail to reject that H0 (which really doesn't prove that it is a good model, but at least the model would then appear to be more appropriate than CSR). If you do a Monte Carlo test you can really use any H0 that you are able to generate realisations from.

In spatial point processes it is common to use envelopes of functional summary statistics in a Monte Carlo test. Using the R package `spatstat` one could test H0 of a Gibbs Hardcore process using the Diggle-Cressie-Loosmore-Ford test based on the L-function (simple transform of Ripley's K-function) like this:

```
## Fit hardcore model to cells data:
fit <- ppm(cells ~ 1, Hardcore())
## Test:
dclf.test(fit, fun = Lest)
```

For more details see the help pages in spatstat:

```
help(Lest)
help(dclf.test)
```

Or have a look in chapter 10 of our recent book:
*Spatial Point Patterns: Methodology and Applications with R*

Comment: The approach described in the first paragraph is a little concerning.  When one "comes up with a plausible model" based on an analysis of the data, it is invalid to use the same data for a formal hypothesis test of that hypothesis: the logic is circular and the p-value, meaningless.

Comment: Formally you are of course right. Before even collecting the data we should decide what we will test. If we have no scientific knowledge of our experiment CSR might be reasonable. If this is rejected we can suggest a new model based on the type of departure and then collect new data to test the hypothesis.